# Imprime dos veces "Fecha incorrecta". Condicionales en Java

Tags: java, condiciones, if

tengo que hacer que imprima "Fecha correcta" cuando escriba una fecha dentro de los rangos considerando meses de 28, 30 y 31 dias. Cuando inserto por consola por ejemplo 31/4/1982  (una fecha que es incorrecta pues Abril tiene 30 dias) me imprime "Fecha incorrecta" dos veces en vez de una. 
¿Dónde está el fallo?

```
package Boleto1;

import java.util.*;

public class Ej_16 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input=new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduce un dia");
        int dia=input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Introduce un mes");
        int mes=input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Introduce un anio");
        int anio=input.nextInt();

        if (anio==0){
            System.out.println("Fecha incorrecta");
        } else {
            if(mes==2 && (dia>0 && dia<=28)){
                System.out.println("Fecha correcta");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Fecha incorrecta");
            }
            if(mes==4 || mes==6 || mes==9 || mes==11){
                if (dia>0 && dia<=30){
                    System.out.println("Fecha correcta");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Fecha incorrecta");
                }
            }
            if (mes==1 || mes==3 || mes==5 || mes==7 || mes==8 || mes==10 || mes==12){
                if (dia>0 && dia<=31){
                    System.out.println("Fecha correcta");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Fecha incorrecta");
                }
            }
        }

    }

    }
```

Comment: Hola Traxomax. La mejor manera de resolver estos problemas de lógica (y de aprender a la vez), es por medio de aprovechar el modo Debug del IDE en que trabajas. Esta te permite correr tu programa una sentencia a la vez y ver claramente en qué momento el programa se desvía del comportamiento esperado y por qué.

Comment: hola sstan, como podria hacerlo en Eclipse?

Comment: Hay muchos artículos y videos en Internet que lo explican bien. Simplemente haz una búsqueda por "como depurar en eclipse".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema obviamente esta en como codificaste la validación.

Fijate que igualmente hubiera sido facil detectar el error, si en cada mensaje de error hubieras agregado un numero, como por ejemplo:

```
if(mes==2 && (dia>0 && dia<=28)){
    System.out.println("Fecha correcta");
} else {
    System.out.println("Fecha incorrecta 1");
}
```

que es justamente, donde esta el problema.

> Introduce un dia
>   Introduce un mes
>   Introduce un anio
>       Fecha incorrecta 1
>       Fecha incorrecta 2

Por pantalla yo veo eso.. Porque?

Por que ese If va a imprimir siempre algo, en los casos correctos, y en los casos incorrectos. Estructuraste esa parte del codigo no como el resto, si no de otra forma, y por eso funciona diferente.

En realidad, si estructuras ese if como los otros

```
if(mes==2)
{
    if (dia>0 && dia<=28)){
        System.out.println("Fecha correcta");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Fecha incorrecta");
    }
}
```

vas a dejar de ver el problema.. pero tendras otro, que pasa con los años bisiestos?

Si esto es un ejercicio de la facultad, te dejo para que lo pienses.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes tratar de implementar tu código con LocalDate, el cual cuenta con un método "of(year, month, dayOfMonth)" que recibe como parámetros, el día, mes y año de tipo entero, de esta forma si la fecha que genera no es válida lanzara una excepción, así puedes mostrar el mensaje "Fecha incorrecta" o "Fecha correcta".

Ejemplo de implementación de LocalDate en tu código:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Introduce un dia");
    int day = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Introduce un mes");
    int month = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Introduce un año");
    int year = sc.nextInt();

    try {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
        System.out.println("Fecha correcta");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Fecha incorrecta");
    }
}
```

De esta forma evitas el generar if anidados y el código no queda tan enredado.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: hola david no llevo mucho tiempo en la programacion y desconocía LocalDate, por ello debia hacerlos con condicionales, igualmente gracias por la respuesta

Comment: bueno LocalDate reemplaza por asi decirlo a Date y Calendar de Java, esta mas estandarizado y sirve bastante a la hora de implementar algoritmos con fechas. Espero que te sirva y lo consideres en tus futuras aplicaciones.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con David. Java tiene una clase dedicada a las fechas y te permite validarlas sin hacer tantos ifs anidados que pueden inducir fácilmente a error.

Con la clase Date le dices una fecha, y si la fecha no es válida se producirá una excepción. La capturas. Si no has capturado ninguna excepción, la fecha es correcta. Si has capturado una excepción, se la pides de nuevo.